# How to stop the execution of a thread in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, nsthread

I want to stop the execution of the thread.I used "iscancelled" but there is something going wrong..After cancelling the thread it's execution does not stop.

```
   NSLog(@"YES-------%d,%d", [myThread isExecuting], [myThread isCancelled]);//(OutPut--1,0)
   [myThread cancel];
if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) 
     {
    [NSThread exit];
 }
   NSLog(@"YES-------%d,%d", [myThread isExecuting], [myThread isCancelled]);//(OutPut--1,1)
```

How is it possible that after canceling the thread it's execution does not stop????

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty certain `[myThread cancel]` is meant to signal ***another*** thread in your program to cancel.

If you want to cancel the current thread, just do `[NSThread exit];`

Answer (score 2):

use this in your thread to stop itself -

`[NSThread exit];`

you can also use `cancel` method check out this - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html